# Unable to play audio in Java using MediaPlayerClass

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play music using the `MediaPlayer` class but I am unable to. I would like to know where I am messing up or what is not happening.
Below is my code for the `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RUNTIME_PERMISSION_CODE = 2;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<MusicList> musicListArrayList;
    private Context context;
    Cursor cursor;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            // viewHolder.getItemId();
            // viewHolder.getItemViewType();
            // viewHolder.itemView;
            MusicList musicList = musicListArrayList.get(position);
            SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            audioPlayer(musicList);
        }
    };
    public void audioPlayer(MusicList musicList){
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(musicList.getMusic()));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,10,0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        musicListArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, musicListArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        createListData();
    }

    private void createListData() {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
        String[] selectionArgument = {"%Music%"};
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC ,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TRACK +","+ MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()){
                String artist=c.getString(0);
                String name = artist.substring(artist.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                MusicList musicList=new MusicList(name);
                musicListArrayList.add(musicList);
            }
            c.close();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},RUNTIME_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error and no music is being played.

```
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1117)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1063)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:999)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:978)
        at ultramodern.activity.musicplayer.MainActivity.audioPlayer(MainActivity.java:62)
        at ultramodern.activity.musicplayer.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
```

I am looking for assistance

Comment: Can you please provide more details like device API, full stack trace etc?

Comment: Your problem is caused in line 1117, check what's behind `musicList.getMusic()`.

Comment: @GGK on the same line, I had set data source as "getApplicationContext, uri" where uri was "MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL..." but the same error was displayed

Comment: check this `uri. do have access on it? for debugging, use a file instead the uri.